# non-standard import in standard package windows

Tags: go

I can't seem to run my go code because of this error

> non-standard import "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5" in standard package "goprojects/search"

Main.go is located at: C:\Go\src\goprojects\search\main.go

GOROOT is C:\Go

GOPATH is C:\Go\src\goprojects (tried adding my current working directory here \search, but didnt help)

when I run "go get gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5" I get the imported files in C:\Go\src\goprojects\src\gopkg.in\olivere\elastic.v5

visual studio code is giving me this message

> cannot find package "go.pkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5" in any of:
>
> C:\Go\src\vendor\gopkg.in\olivere\elastic.v5 (vendor tree)
>
> C:\Go\src\gopkg.in\olivere\elastic.v5 (from $GOROOT)
>
> C:\Go\src\goprojects\src\gopkg.in\olivere\elastic.v5 (from $GOPATH)

my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    elastic "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/search", search)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func search(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    searchString := r.URL.Query().Get("q")
    fmt.Println("Searching for" + searchString)

    // Create a client
    client, err := elastic.NewClient()

    w.Write([]byte(searchString))
}
```

Comment: You cannot put your code in GOROOT. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: realized that, the video tutorial i followed put it there though, so I did the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

moved my goprojects out of my GoRoot path and into a separate folder in C:\goprojects and replaced my GoPath with the new path and it worked.